# Better alternative for CommitMonitor

Tags: svn, version-control

In past I've used SVN Monitor and was very happy with it. Now it looks like SVN Monitor is paid.

I tried CommitMonitor, but don't like it as much as SVN Monitor.
What I don't like about Commit Manager is it's GUI:

- I can not click on particular file to see it's modifications as in SVN Monitor.
- When you click on particular commit, you receive list of files to see their changes.
  But Commit Monitor doesn't show in the list files changed in the same commit from different location it monitors for.
- When you open Commit Monitor GUI, it shows oldest commits, while I want to see latest.
- ..............

I read about alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992/best-svn-tools), but it's passed almost 3 years from then.

What are're using for SVN monitoring (Windows)?

Comment: The link you posted redirects to 404, luckily here the archive team has a back up [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130306091045/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992/what-are-the-best-svn-tools)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is your purpose to track SVN changes?
If you are monitoring code to initiate some soft of Code Reviews, I would suggest using a tool that encapsulates the review process (besides alerting code changes). I use the Atlassian (Crucible for code reviews and FishEye to monitor/alert on commits) and it works great.

TeamCity is good to fire CI builds on commits to source... not the best way to find out what changed in the source.

Cheers,
Savinder

Comment: FishEye looks a type of program I'm looking - I just to want to be notified about commits, to be involved in software involvement.

Comment: Well, I love FishEye but you have to pay for it! \
If you are an OpenSource fan, you might want to look at OpenGroak http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+opengrok/ In one of my previous avatars, we had it implemented and it worked perfect.

Comment: In my place we already use confluence and think to migrate from bugzilla to Jira. So, other Attssian tools may be considered too. I personally prefer OOS tools for personal usage, so I can use it at home too. Actually I'm looking for simple tool like CommitMonitor, which merely gives commit notification, but maybe it's my narrow vision :)

Comment: Does anyone know why Commit Monitor has nearly the same GUI as SVN Monitor?? Under the hood, is this the same tool?

Answer (score 8):

You can install [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) along with your SVN server, and get [RSS feeds](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRss) of repository changes with your favorite RSS desktop notifier, like [Feed Notifier](http://www.feednotifier.com/). Trac and Feed Notifier are both free.

After you've configured Trac by adding your repository with trac-admin, you can subscribe to the RSS feed provided at the bottom of the timeline page.

At each commit the RSS feeds a new entry:

```
Changeset in repo [<RevNumber>]: <commit-message>
```

The feed link leads you directly to the changeset page, which gives which file changed and the diffs if they're text files.

See examples for the Trac project: [RSS feed](http://trac.edgewall.org/timeline?changeset=on&repo-=on&repo-cboos=on&repo-jomae=on&repo-psuter=on&repo-rblank=on&repo-ticket-links=on&milestone=on&ticket=on&wiki=on&max=50&authors=&daysback=90&format=rss), [RSS entry](http://trac.edgewall.org/changeset/10848)

Or, in the same manner of Trac, you can use [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/), which also provides RSS feed. Maybe more lightweight...

Comment: +1 Yes, it is free and works on Windows

Comment: @CharlesB Actually I'm satisfied with how Commit Manager notifies about commits (pop-up window). What I don't like about Commit Manager is it's GUI - it's clumsy and there're some stuff I don't how it works (I've updated the question)

Comment: @CharelsB - this way I'll receive notification about commit, but I can not view the commit changes. Correct?

Comment: @dimba: See my edits; you view commit changes by going to the RSS entry link

Comment: @CharlesB Probably closest to what CM does, but IMHO still convenient than CM

Comment: @dimba did you mean less convenient?

Answer (score 4):

CommitMonitor still the best tool to monitor svn changes in windows. very light and do the work. [that's based on my current exp.]

Comment: CommitMonitor was already ruled out in the question and no explanation to why it still should be considered.

Comment: @asken: i already went through all the tools 3 months ago, and that's was my conclusion after 3 days of deep research. so instead of just posting tools list without knowing how good or bad they are, i added my 2 cents. sometimes a person change a thought after seeing that others are really happy with the tools they use.

Answer (score 2):

Free one:
http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/

Comment: this is close, but IMHO it monitors to see is local copy is out of date. Contrary, I'm looking to monitor repository.

Comment: Why don't you buy SVN Monitor? If you're soo happy with it $69 is pretty cheap. Looks like I'll be buying it myself.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Using TeamCity**

   You can use [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) - [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server. It is very powerful tool and can be used for monitoring needs. 
   In case you are using java and [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) - IDEA has integration with TeamCity.

   TeamCity has free version and works on Windows.
2. **Using IDE like IntelliJ IDEA**

   The IDEA has *[Changes list](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html)* - the list of local changes (to commit), the list changes on server (to update), and history list (all commits).

   IDEA has free version and works on Windows.

Comment: @CharlesB If talking about TeamCity - yes. But it can be a push for using CI (if not already) ;)

Comment: @AlexK Both SVN Monitor and Commit Monitor sit in tray and do polling svn repository on predefined tree(s). If new commit is seen, a pop up screen appears. This what I'm looking.

Answer (score -1):

I actually use the combo TortoiseSVN & AnkhSVN and it works very well.

I don't really know svn monitor but the tuple Tortoise/AnkhSVN seems to do all the things you mentionned.

> Tortoise : http://tortoisesvn.net/
>
> AnkhSvn  : http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Comment: how does it notify about repository updates?